# Object access notation: square bracket (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, notation

I don't know how to read this piece of code:

```
var byName = {};
ancestry.forEach(function(person){ byName[person.name] = person;]);
console.log(byName["Phil"]);
```

What I'm confused about is the "byName[person.name] = person" part of the code.

1) what does byName[person.name] mean? Why is square bracket notation used and not a dot notation?

2) Why is it equated to person (byName[person.name] = person) and how does that work?

ps: ancestry is a JSON file as a string that's available in the sandbox of my ebook.

Answer (score 2):

Dot notation uses an identifier. `x.foo` gets the `foo` property.

Square bracket notation takes a string. `x["foo"]` gets the `foo` property.

The string can come from any expression.

```
var person = {};
person.name = "foo";
x[person.name]
```

… gets the `foo` property

`byName[person.name] = person;` just breaks down to "Create a new property named after the current person on the `byName` object and make its value the current person object"

Comment: Too bad this is marked as a dup, your answer is far better then the linked dup.

Answer (score 2):

This code loops through `ancestry` and adds to the object `byName`. The `byName[person.name] = person` is adding a new element to the `byName` object. The key is the `person.name` and the set value is the `person`. In other words, this code allows a way to quickly lookup a `person` object from it's name. The last line of code demonstrates this in action.